# Ionic4 and Intro.js display problems

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, intro.js

After installing Intro.js to an Ionic4 app, the tooltips don't display correctly out of the box.

Running introJs().start();  starts the tooltip but display is wrong.

The tooltips should display on the correct element and that element must be shown over the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to make introjs to add to your component root. By default intro.js adds divs to the body element, so tooltips doesn't display ok. To Start intro.js  on home.page.ts you must specify with document.querySelector(yourcomponentselector)

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import * as introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor() {}

  showHelp(){
    introJs(document.querySelector("app-home")).setOptions({
      'nextLabel': 'Next step',
      'prevLabel': 'Previous step',
      'skipLabel': 'Don\'t bother me!',
      'doneLabel': 'Finish'
    }).start(); 
  }
}
```

Additionaly, some ionic components 'content' css property must be overriden.

```html
ion-nav,
ion-tab,
ion-tabs,
ion-list {
    contain: none;
}
```

I've uploaded a example project at github: https://github.com/konum/ionic4-introjs/

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) you are brave enough, i made a wrapper package for intro.js to be used as a directive on an Angular application.

This is a private (@) package that i made for me and my company so it's not well documented at all, but is surely mantained

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@esfaenza/ngx-introjs

Little guide:

1) Install the package with

```
npm install @esfaenza/ngx-introjs
```

(you should check the version you need. from Angular version 8 onward i followed Angular's version, from 8 downward just try the last available build)

2) In your module:

```
import { IntroJsModule } from "@esfaenza/ngx-introjs"
...
@NgModule({
imports: [IntroJsModule, etc...],
declarations: [your stuff],
exports: [your stuff]
})
```

3) In your component's .ts define the Intro's data

```
public const IntroItems = {
'Group': '1',
'1': 'Step 1 description',
'2': 'Step 2 description'
};
```

4) In your HTML attach the directive where you need it

```
[intro]="IntroItems" [Order]="1"
```

5) To make the presentation start, inject IntroJsService like so in your component:

```
import { IntroJsService } from "@esfaenza/ngx-introjs";
constructor(public introService: IntroJsService, etc...) { }
```

6) and use it like so:

```
this.introService.start(null, '1');
```

7) If you want to change the default Options of intro.js you can use

```
this.introService.setOptions(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that maybe can have this issue, I found another alternative to fix it.

```
const introInstance = this.introJS.setOptions({
  nextLabel: '<ion-icon name="arrow-forward-outline"></ion-icon>',
  prevLabel: '<ion-icon name="arrow-back-outline"></ion-icon>',
  steps,
});

introInstance.start();

introInstance.onbeforechange((targetElement: HTMLElement) => {
  targetElement.scrollIntoView();
});
```

Scroll to target element using onbeforechange intro js callback.